# How to find the path along a line until it first intersects a polygon?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a path as an ordered series of points which intersects a polygon. I would like to extract the portion of the line before the first polygon intersection.

I have tried to split the path by calculating the difference with the polygon, but the line is also split on its self-intersections (see example). I need to extract the full portion of the path from the start all the way up until it first intersects the polygon (blue square in the example).

```r
# A wonky line that intersects itself   
l = sf::st_linestring(cbind(cos((0:100) * pi / 50), sin((0:100) * pi / 15 )))
# A polygon that intersects the line
p = sf::st_polygon(list(cbind(c(-.3, -.3, -.2, -.2, -.3), c(-.3, -.2, -.2, -.3, -.3))))

# Visualisation of the problem
plot(l)
plot(p, add = TRUE, col = "blue")

# Taking the first fragment of the difference does not work as the path intersects and divides itself
d = sf::st_difference(l, p)
plot(sf::st_linestring(d[[1]]), add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

In the example, the path is segmented by all intersections (even on itself) so the first portion of the path does not extend all the way to the polygon. I suspect there is a function in the sf package specifically for my purpose - but I have not found it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self-intersecting line string isn't "simple" (see `st_is_simple(l)`) even though it is "valid" (see `st_is_valid(l)`), and `sf` here is giving you a simple feature. What we need to do is work with the simple LINESTRINGs and rebuild the longer line feature...

First diff the wiggly line with the polygon - `d` is then a multilinestring:

```
> d = st_difference(l,p)
```

If we convert it to an `sfc` and then cast it to LINESTRING we get the parts in separate LINESTRING geometries:

```
> dl = st_cast(st_sfc(d),"LINESTRING")
```

and there are 8 of them:

```
> length(dl)
[1] 8
```

So starting with the first one, how many do we need to follow until we hit the polygon? Let's get the intersections of the segments with the polygon - this is a sparse list - elements are length 0 if no intersection, greater than 0 if there is an intersection:

```
> sint = st_intersects(dl,p)
```

The first element of that list **that isn't zero** is the first line string that hits the polygon:

```
> min(which(lengths(sint)>0))
[1] 3
```

Which means our line up to the polygon is the first three linestrings:

```
> dl[1:3]
Geometry set for 3 features 
geometry type:  LINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -0.220294 ymin: -0.9945219 xmax: 1 ymax: 0.9945219
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
LINESTRING (1 0, 0.9980267 0.2079117, 0.9921147...
LINESTRING (0.9510565 0.8660254, 0.9297765 0.95...
LINESTRING (0.309017 -0.8660254, 0.309017 -0.86...
```

You can union these into one feature and plot:

```
> plot(l)
> plot(p,add=TRUE,col="red")
> topoly = st_union(dl[1:3])
> plot(topoly, add=TRUE, lwd=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

It was the second step: converting the `multilinestring` into a list of `linestrings` that was crucial. As a newcomer to the `sf` package it was confusing why `st_intersects` should return a single value for a `multilinestring` or `multipoint`. 
The distinction between a multi-line geometry and multiple line geometries clears this up completely.